# Swift - Dynamic Array of Struct

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground, swift-structs

I have a struct:

```
public struct Deque<T> {

    private var array = [T]()

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return array.isEmpty
    }

    public var count: Int {
        return array.count
    }

    public mutating func enqueue(_ element: T) { //inserts element at end
        array.append(element)
    }

    public mutating func enqueueFront(_ element: T) { //inserts element at beginning
        array.insert(element, at: 0)
    }
}
```

And I declare the struct like this:

```
var burst = [Deque<Int>()]
```

And I initialize it like this in a for loop:

```
for i in 0..<9 {
    for j in 0..<10{
    if processes[i][j] != 0{
        burst[i].enqueue(processes[i][j])
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to initialize index 0 of my struct successfully, however, whenever i get to index 1, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range

How do I declare and initialize a dynamic array of structs in swift?

Comment: Unrelated, but you would get better clarity and performance if add an initializer to `Deque` that takes an array of initial values. This would be particularly useful, because it would allow you to initialize the `Deque` using a `map` call over those ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var burst = [Deque<Int>()]
```

This declares `burst` to be an array of **1** `Deque` object.  You're trying to access `burst[i]` where `i` is greater than 0, which is outside of `burst` range.

You can use Array `init(repeating:count:)` initializer ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init)) like so:

```
var burst = Array<Deque<Int>>(repeating: Dequeue<Int>(), count: 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating only one element of type "Deque" in the "burst" array with this command:

```
var burst = [Deque<Int>()]  //There is only one element inside the array
```

That's why when you try to access the "burst" array with i > 0, it crashes.
You need to init a new Deque object before appending to the array, then call

```
burst[i]
```

later

You can do it this way:

```
for i in 0..<9 {
  for j in 0..<10{
    if processes[i][j] != 0{
        var queue = Deque<Int>()
        queue.enqueue(processes[i][j])
        burst.append(queue)
    }
  }
}
```